# GitHub - Unsynchronized Commit?

Tags: git, github

I made a bunch of changes to files in a git repository. Before I committed anything I was asked to commit some other files someone else had for me (coming from an SVN repository). I dropped those files into my project folder, picked them from amongst all of the changed files from earlier and committed them. Now I need to Sync the branch to get these to move to Github but when I try to sync I get "Uncommitted Changes. Please commit your changes before syncing".

I assume this refers to all of the files I had changed previously? However, I do not want those so be committed... they are not ready. I only want to commit this small subset of files. What does one do in this situation? How do I move all of the changes I've made that I do NOT want to be a part of this commit out of the way, for lack of a better word, and get the part I DO want to change into the github repository?

I'm using the GitHub App but can do it from the command line if needed... just not sure what needs to be done.

---

Here are some screenshots to make it clearer:

At the bottom of my list of changed files is the commit I want to move:

[image]

Trying to get that commit to move over to github I click the Sync button and get:

[image]

What is the solution? How do I get these "uncommitted changes" out of the way? Obviously I am new to git so I am not clear on the correct approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know if the GitHub app provides this functionality (though I would kind of expect it to), but git has a function called "git stash" which takes all your uncommitted changes and stashes them away in a special place. This leaves you with a pristine working copy (without those changes), where you can do whatever you need to, and then use `git stash pop` (or `git stash apply`) to reapply your uncommitted changes. I encourage you to read the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-stash).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Kevin. I've been using git a bit more lately but as a long time svn user I usually just use it like that. Not ideal, clearly, but it works until something "different" happens and I'm caught out. It's one of those "I'll read up on this as soon as I can come up for air" and then, it's been a month and no air.

Comment: @gaoshan88: While git can certainly be used in an svn-like mode, I strongly encourage you to take an evening sometime and start to learn about the more git-like ways to do things. There's a lot of power and flexibility in git, and once you learn how to do more stuff with it, you'll never want to go back to the constraints of svn again.

Comment: Frankly I hate that fact that I have to stash my changes and then go in and do a manual merge later.

Answer (score 18):

In the **GitHub for Mac** GUI client, go to **Repository** > **Push** on the menubar.

This will upload any unsynced commits to the GitHub server. Since this does not download any new code, the GitHub client will not force you to commit all your changes. This is useful if you have a bunch of local changes that are not ready to commit, but you also have several local changes that are ready to commit.

This seems easier than (although conceptually equivalent to) the previous suggested answers involving the git command-line interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thought the following discussion

[Committing Files Back to GitHub for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116532/committing-files-back-to-github-for-windows/13117323#13117323)

may help readers of this question.