# Recovering a Git Mistake

Tags: git

Fairly new to GIT and need a little help.

Hosting my content on Github. Last night I realized I hadn't pushed my content up to Github in awhile so I opened up the github mac client and did a commit/sync on my project. It said I was 2 commits ahead of the master branch. I was confused...

**1st Mistake** -
So I did a " git reset --hard origin/master", I then synced up with Github.

I open up my laptop the next morning, then open up netbeans and all my work that I did is gone. I'm in panic mode...

So I'm Googling around and find [this page](http://devjosh.com/undoing-git-reset-stack-overflow) which describes how to undo a GIT Reset. I followed that pretty well and reset to the previous commit.
Here is my Git relog:

```
ce8d01b HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
fcc0db9 HEAD@{1}: commit: front page
ce8d01b HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to origin/master
a6bda3a HEAD@{3}: commit: front page
cde0712 HEAD@{4}: commit: Fixed Front Page Slider
ce8d01b HEAD@{5}: commit: Fixed Company Scrolling.
dd7b163 HEAD@{6}: commit: Work on company product and home page
4cc4274 HEAD@{7}: commit: Added Company Page
1ebed75 HEAD@{8}: commit (initial): initial
```

After I did git reset HEAD@{1} I opened netbeans and the code still wasn't there so I thought maybe I did the wrong one. So I did it again but this time went to HEAD@{2}. Which is where I am now.

```
a6bda3a HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD@{3}
ce8d01b HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD@{1}
fcc0db9 HEAD@{2}: commit: front page
ce8d01b HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to origin/master
a6bda3a HEAD@{4}: commit: front page
cde0712 HEAD@{5}: commit: Fixed Front Page Slider
ce8d01b HEAD@{6}: commit: Fixed Company Scrolling.
dd7b163 HEAD@{7}: commit: Work on company product and home page
4cc4274 HEAD@{8}: commit: Added Company Page
1ebed75 HEAD@{9}: commit (initial): initial
```

But I still can't see my code. Is there something else I need to do?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Which commit had your code in it?  It looks here like it might be `a6bda3a`, but you say you don't see your code?  Did you try `git checkout @{6.pm.yesterday}` or something like that to just go back to a particular point in time?

Comment: Ok so from your comment Carl. If I now do a git reset HEAD@{4}. Do I need to do a git checkout to see the code or should it populate correctly after doing a git reset?

Comment: Why are you so set on using the `HEAD@{4}` syntax? What's wrong with using the hash or the time-based example I gave?

Comment: Ok gotcha did a git checkout @{3.pm.yesterday}...didn't revert back to my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reflog, a

```
 git reset --hard a6bda3a
```

should restore your content as it was *before* your `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Then, if [GitHub branch is ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643792/6309), I would recommend a:

```
git pull --rebase 
# check everything is still working
# git add and git commit if needed
git push
```

Comment: VonC...thanks for the help. I tried this as well...didn't work.

Comment: @DaveG you mean a6bda3a  isn't the code as committed before your first `git reset --hard`? Don't forget that this command removes any private files and reset the index. So did you had uncommitted work?

Comment: yes, I reverted to a6bda3a and it's not the code. I'm thinking I had uncommitted work...Stupid mistake. There is one saving grace I think. (Forgive me since I usually use the GUI instead of the command line). I now open up the GITHUB GUI and it says I have unsynced commits from 18 hours ago. I'll happily revert to that one. I'm just not sure how to switch there. My alternative is a commit 2 weeks ago :)

Comment: @DaveG would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174324/github-unsynchronized-commit help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/13117323/6309? Did you try a `git stash pop`, just in case the GUI did save your work in progress?

Comment: @DaveG Any time machine feature activated on your Mac which could allow you to get those files back?